# How to send request with a set http_header in Erlang Package a SOAP github package

Tags: soap, wsdl, erlang, elixir

I am using this [erlang-package on Github to work with WSDL and SOAP](https://github.com/bet365/soap), and I am only using the package for Client generation! I have not erlang knowledge at all - only basic elixir.

My Problem:

> How can I send a request with an authorization header?

Lets say the code to test my service looks like the following:

```
connectionCheck() ->

    'WsdlService_client':connectionCheck(
        #'P:connectionCheck'{
            clientSoftwareKennung = "Elixir"},
    _Soap_headers = [],
    _Soap_options = [{url,"http://localhost:8091/myservice/v2.0/connectionCheck"}]).
```

Which parameter needs to be filled in and what do the parameters look like when I need the following header in the resulting `http-request`?

```
Authorization: Basic <placeholder encodeded user password>
```

Thanks!

Comment: i do not need a soap header..  i need that in the header of my http request.

Comment: idk what u mean, i cant add an addintional paramter, -> i guess the entry have to be in _Soap_options[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by myself.

If you need to pass some http-Headers to your Soap-Request you can do it like that:

```
_Soap_options = [{url,"http://localhost:8091/myservice/v2.0/connectionCheck"},{http_headers, [{"Authorization","Basic Encoded User-Pass"}]}]).
```